# mysql --defaults-extra-file with user/password yields "Access denied..."

Tags: mysql

Using mysql 14.14 distr 5.7.22 on Ubuntu 16.04

An installation script for Koha uses the following to log onto mysql and automatically create databases:

```
mysql --defaults-file-extra=/etc/mysql/koha-common.cnf
```

/etc/mysql/koha-common.cnf is a symlink to /etc/mysql/debian.cnf which contains

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     =  localhost
user     =  debian-sys-maint
password =  thepassword
socket   =  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     =   localhost
user     =  debian-sys-maint
password =  thepassword
socket   =  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

(I have changed the password).

When I run this command directly from the command line, I get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If I run

```
mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
```

and manually type in the password, mysql logs me in with no problem.

It seems that mysql is reading the extra file, since it gets the username, but doesn't seem to get the password. The actual password is all alpha characters, but I have tried it with the password enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Does the `debian-sys-maint` user have `localhost` defined as an allowed host in the mysql.user table?

Comment: @ThatGuyinIT. When I "select user,host from mysql.user;, it shows (among others) debian-sys-maint localhost

Comment: Do the password hashes match?

Comment: Honestly, I would delete the symlink and  create a file named /etc/mysql/koha-common.cnf with credentials that you create just for koha.  I wouldn't recommend using the debian-sys-maint user.  The application should have its own credentials, which will later allow you to lock the user down to minimal privileges.

Comment: This process is actually part of an automated install set up by the Koha installation. It created that debian.cnf and symlink file with user and password. The user in question is used by the Koha system to automate the database creation process. When the install process failed, I debugged and found the error at this case above. BTW, I tested using both the file and the symlink

Comment: Regarding password hashes: not sure how I would check that. The password is given in clear text in the cnf file. As I stated in the original question, when I type in the password manually it works.

Comment: Koha also looks to not recommend using MySQL 5.7: `Koha does not work well with MySQL 5.7 which is shipped with Ubuntu 16.04. use MariaDB instead.`

Comment: You can use `select user,host,password from mysql.user;` to verify the password hashes match up.

Comment: Password hashes match ;-)

Comment: You m,ight want to look at [this link](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages#Ubuntu_16.04_and_MySQL_5.7).

Comment: After experimentation, the best I can determine is that there is a problem with MySQL 5.7 which prevents it from properly using the --defaults-extra-file. Giving up... Launching new instance using MariaDB does seem to work.